# Formula that looks at value in a cell and depending on what the value is

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

*I'm using Excel 2010*

I have a number in cell A1.

In Cell B1 i need a formula that says if the number in cell A1 is 25 then put 'account1', if the number in cell A1 is 58 then put 'account2', if the number in cell A1 is 200 then put 'account3'

Im not sure which formula to use or how to achieve the result?

Your help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Raystafarian has given the correct answer.  However, you may want to consider whether you will need to, in the future, have more than 3 assignments, or the assignments may change...  If so, a VLOOKUP would be an easier to maintain solution (but a harder formula to understand)).

Comment: @Madball73 is correct, using a lookup function for larger data-sets is much easier to maintain, but for your simple example, it's probably easier to understand the functionality of the if() function.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need nested `if()` statements, like:

> if 25 then Account1 otherwise (else), if 58 then Account2 otherwise...

`=IF(A1=25,"account1",IF(A1=58,"account2",""))`

The format for the [`IF()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/if-function-HP010069829.aspx) function is `IF(logical_test, value_if_true, [value_if_false])` and you're just placing another `IF()` function in the `[value_if_false]` repeatedly.