# Excel 2010 Multiple Conditions and More Than 2 Outcomes

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I need some help!

I have 4 conditions and more than 2 different outcomes dependent upon the condition so strugglig with IF/AND/OR statements. All data is dates. a2 is the reference date:

```
Condition 1 b2<>"", c2<>"" - true = (b2-a2) , false - see other conditions 
Condition 2 b2<>", c2="" - true = (b2-a2) , false - see other conditions
Condition 3 b2="", c2="" - true = (today()-a2), false, see other conditions
Condition 4 b2="", c2<>"" - true = "", false, see other conditions
```

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you are asking. Please elaborate how your data is laid out and what you are trying to accomplish. Also include any existing formula(s) you are using.

Comment: Are those `b2 <> " "` ? As in `isblank(b2)=0`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Formula that looks at value in a cell and depending on what the value is](http://superuser.com/questions/748937/formula-that-looks-at-value-in-a-cell-and-depending-on-what-the-value-is)

Comment: b2<>"" implies cell b2 is occupied with information, in this case, a date.

Comment: I have 3 dates, Refer, Treat and Discharge

Answer (score 2):

Exactly as you wrote it, it would be this:

```
=IF(AND(B2<>"",C2<>""),B2-A2,IF(AND(B2<>"",C2=""),B2-A2,IF(AND(B2="",C2=""),TODAY()-A2,IF(AND(B2="",C2<>""),"","How did you get here?"))))
```

However, the first two conditions ignore C2 and the last two will only be checked if B2 is blank so you can shorten it to just:

```
=IF(B2<>"",B2-A2,IF(C2="",TODAY()-A2,""))
```

Comment: Genius fixer 1234. Thank you very much. I got here through lots of frustration almost doing what you showed but clealry not accomplishing a whole heck of a lot.

Comment: Glad to help. If it worked, mark it as answered so it'll drop off the unanswered page and other needing help can find it more easily.